# NativeBase accordion's "renderHeader " Property showing undefined value for the parameter "expanded"

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

I am using the native-base accordion in one of my react-native projects. I need to customize its header and for that, I have gone through its documentation. The method which is mentioned in the doc is not properly working. The `expanded` parameter of `_renderHeader(title, expanded)` function showing undefined when I checked its value in the alert. It should give me `true` or `false`  Below is the code is given in the native-base documentation. Can anyone guide me how it will give me `true` or `false` based on open and close accordion?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Header, Content, Accordion, View, Text } from "native-base";
const dataArray = [
  { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Third Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" }
];
export default class AccordionCustomHeaderContentExample extends Component {
  _renderHeader(title, expanded) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 10, justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "#A9DAD6" }}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: "600" }}>
          {" "}{title}
        </Text>
        {expanded
          ? <Icon style={{ fontSize: 18 }} name="remove-circle" />
          : <Icon style={{ fontSize: 18 }} name="add-circle" />}
      </View>
    );
  }
  _renderContent(content) {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#e3f1f1", padding: 10, fontStyle: "italic" }}
      >
        {content}
      </Text>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Content padder>
          <Accordion
            dataArray={dataArray}
            renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            renderContent={this._renderContent}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to accordion interface with syntactic difference in params(i.e. expanded param was missing in their code). Native base team has resolved this issue few days before. Hence you need to remove your node_modules folder, then need to install the plugin by using following commands:

```
npm install native-base --save
react-native link
```

I think, this may be the cause of the issue you are facing, please find 'renderHeader' old code:

```
renderHeader?: (item: any) => React.ReactElement<any>;
```

They have modified the 'renderHeader' code as follows by adding 'expanded' param:

```
renderHeader?: (item: any, expanded: boolean) => React.ReactElement<any>;
```

Please find more details at this link https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/2160

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Guru, is above specified issue still persist?

Answer (score 0):

```
_renderHeader({title, expanded}) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 10, justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "#A9DAD6" }}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize:20 }}>
          {" "}{title}
        </Text>
        {expanded
          ? <Icon style={{ fontSize: 18 }} name="remove-circle" />
          : <Icon style={{ fontSize: 18 }} name="add-circle" />}
      </View>
    );
  }
  _renderContent({content}) {
    return (
      <Text
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#e3f1f1", padding: 10, fontStyle: "italic" }}
      >
        {content}
      </Text>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Add inside object format in function type. Its working

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
renderHeader({title}) {
    return (
      <View
        style={{ flexDirection: "row", padding: 10, justifyContent: "space-between", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "#A9DAD6" }}
      >
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize:20 }}>
          {" "}{title}
        </Text>
        {arguments[1]
          ? <Icon style={{ fontSize: 18 }} name="remove-circle" />
          : <Icon style={{ fontSize: 18 }} name="add-circle" />}
      </View>
    );
  }
```